# Installing line6 drivers using subversion

Tags: svn

I am trying to install gearbox on 14.04.1 using subversion.  I've entered the svn directory via svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/line6linux/code/driver/trunk, but I don't know what to do from here.

I'm following instructions located here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1163608 (the `url` has changed since this article was written)

I can see that the terminal is still in my local directory, so there is no make file to be executed.  I don't really understand how `svn` works, so help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

(Gearbox is the only reason I'm still running a dual-boot machine... help me change that)

Answer (score 0):

If you checked out from the repository without specifying a local working directory name i.e.

```
svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/line6linux/code/driver/trunk
```

then the default working directory name will be the same as the final URL component i.e. `trunk`, and you would therefore need to `cd trunk` to find the checked out source  and `Makefile`.

If you specified a local directory name for the checkout

```
svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/line6linux/code/driver/trunk somedir
```

then you would `cd somedir` instead. After that, you should just need to

```
make
sudo make install
```

There is extensive documentation for SVN in the ['SVN Red Book'](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).